# tensorflow Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected TensorProto got Variable. for field Value.tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I am trying to save variables through checkpoints to introduce fault tolerance to my program. The following is my configuration:-

```
import tensorflow as tf
global_step_tensor = tf.Variable(10, trainable=False, name='global_step')
x = tf.constant(2)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:0"):
    y1 = tf.Variable(x + 300)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:1"):
    y2 = tf.Variable(x**2)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:2"):
    y3 = tf.Variable(5*x)

with tf.device("/job:local/task:3"):
    y0 = tf.Variable(x - 66)
    y = y0 + y1 + y2 + y3

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver([y])

ChiefSessionCreator = tf.train.ChiefSessionCreator(scaffold=None, master='grpc://localhost:2222', config=None, checkpoint_dir='/tensorflow/checkpoints')
saver_hook = tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir='/tensorflow/checkpoints', save_secs=10, save_steps=None, saver=saver, checkpoint_basename='model.ckpt', scaffold=None)
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=None, save_secs=10, output_dir='/tensorflow/savepoints', summary_writer=None, scaffold=None, summary_op=tf.Summary(tf.Summary.Value(tensor=y)))

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master='grpc://localhost:2222', is_chief=True, checkpoint_dir='/tensorflow/checkpoints', 
    scaffold=None, hooks=[saver_hook,summary_hook], chief_only_hooks=None, save_checkpoint_secs=10, save_summaries_steps=None, config=None) as sess:

    while not sess.should_stop():
        sess.run(model)

    while not sess.should_stop():
        result = sess.run(y)
        print(result)
```

In this, the `CheckpointSaveHook` saves tf.Variable in `saver` and `SummarySaverHook` takes a tensor input in `summary_op`. The error I get is:-

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From add_1.py:25 in <module>.: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_1.py", line 34, in <module>
    summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=None, save_secs=10, output_dir='/home/chaitanya/tensorflow/codes/savepoints', summary_writer=None, scaffold=None, summary_op=tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tensor=y)]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 532, in init
    _ReraiseTypeErrorWithFieldName(message_descriptor.name, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 460, in _ReraiseTypeErrorWithFieldName
    six.reraise(type(exc), exc, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 530, in init
    copy.MergeFrom(new_val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1233, in MergeFrom
    "expected %s got %s." % (cls.__name__, type(msg).__name__))
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected TensorProto got Tensor. for field Value.tensor
```

How do I rectify this?

Comment: Could you try `tf.summary.tensor_summary(name="y", tensor=y)` as the `summary_op` argument to `SummarySaverHook`?

Comment: I have changed the code as advised but now I'm getting an error as such:-
[http://pastebin.com/raw/CvPyB4H0](http://pastebin.com/raw/CvPyB4H0)
(I didn't change any other part of the code)

Comment: Maybe you have an old checkpoint lying around? If deleting that doesn't help, which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: I ran the program again after deleting all the checkpoints and savepoints from the last run. The same problem persists. I am using the v0.12.0 of tensorflow.

Comment: Can you reproduce this today with TF 1.0?